# owl carousel 2 same dots transition speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I have a one item carousel set in this way

```
owl.owlCarousel({
    items:1,
    loop:true,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:5000,
    autoplayHoverPause:true,
    autoplaySpeed: 1000,
    dotsSpeed: 1000
});
```

[image]

When I go from 1 to 2 (or between any two points lying next to each other) the transition delay 1 seconds (expected) but when I go from 1 to 4 the transition takes much more time.

I want the transition speed to be always the same (1s) regardless the distance of the points.

To clarify, when it is in dot 1 and I move to dot 2, I want the element in slide 2, delays one seconds in showing , and when going from 1 to 4 the element in the slide 4 delays one seconds in showing too.

**[Here a jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/jf33nnwf/)**

Note in the jsfiddle I put a `span.test` that has a 1s delay animation so when the slide move in auto play or you go from 1 to 2 just when it finished the transition, the span.test appear but when you go from 1 to 4 the `span.test` arrive already showing.

I will be grateful if you can help me

Comment: Please show it in a JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet or on a JSFiddle.

Comment: @5ervant I added a jsfiddle example whit a small explanation for better understanding of what is happening

Comment: _"Uncaught TypeError: `$(...).owlCarousel` is not a function"_

Comment: @5ervant where did you see that error?, I can't see it in my jsfiddle

Comment: Actually what I'm seeing is _"Uncaught ReferenceError: `$` is not defined"_. And after I include _jQuery 2.1.3_ in **Frameworks & Extensions**, that what I'm seeing. Could you first make your JSFiddle working.

Comment: @5ervant actually my jsfiddle works perfectly, if you check **External Resourse** you will notice the link to jquery.min.js

Comment: so what you're saying you're trying to animate that square background from each item, having 1s delay on the transition; OR is the delay suppose to work on the item, like click on dot 2, wait 1s and then it will slide/move to the next slide? or the dots themselves?

Comment: @Crispy-George I want the time that it takes to go from one slide to another to be always the same, for instance if it goes from slide 1 to slide 2 it takes 1s, and if it goes from 1 to 4 I want this to take 1s too. the red square which has 1s delay is only used to examplify that when it goes from slides which aren't one next to the other the transition will take longer than 1s, being this the case the square would be shown right in the moment the transition ends and as you can see in the jsfiddle the square 1s delay ends before the trans ends that's why the square is already visualized.

Comment: @Yandy_Viera did you get this ?